# Selecting the value of an entire dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I'm making a simple quiz game and I'm having some trouble with calculating the results. The problem is really simple, I need to find out how to say if `clicked1` has a value more than the whole dictionary it is in then do this function. Here is the code for the dictionary and the function I'm trying to make. Also, if someone could explain why `possibilities.value` doesn't work for my problem that would be much appreciated.

```
var possibilities = {
    'clicked1': 0,
    'clicked2': 0,
    'clicked3': 0,
    'clicked4': 0,
};

function results(){
    if (possibilities['clicked1'] > possibilities){
        console.log("it worked");
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you want to check if `clicked1` is greater than the amount of properties in `possibilities`?

Comment: I want to find out if 'clicked1' is greater than the value of 'clicked2' , 3 ,4 so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate through `Object.values` with `every`:

```js
var possibilities = {
    'clicked1': 0,
    'clicked2': 0,
    'clicked3': 0,
    'clicked4': 0,
};

if (Object.values(possibilities).every(val => possibilities.clicked1 >= val || val == possibilities.clicked1)) {
  console.log("It works!");
}
```

Comment: No problem @TheNuthouse, if my answer fixed your problem please be sure to upvote and accept it.

Comment: Works fine, but i'm having trouble understanding the syntax, ive only been coding with JavaScript for maybe 2 weeks now, please explain if you can, just by sticking some notes by the important parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). You can also check if the max value of the object values by using [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and Rest Parameters

```js
var ps = {
    'clicked1': 4,
    'clicked2': 1,
    'clicked3': 2,
    'clicked4': 3,
};
if(Object.keys(ps).every(key => ps[key] <= ps.clicked1)){
  console.log("worked")
}
//Second Method:
//Object.values(ps) will return '[4,1,2,3]' And then using ... all values
//are passed to function Math.max() single argument. and it will return the max value out of those and then compare that value with you desired value
if(Math.max(...Object.values(ps)) === ps.clicked1){
    console.log("Worked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that is quite similar to what you had in your attempt.

Basically loop over the keys and values in the dictionary, ignoring the value for the key, 'clicked1':

```js
let possibilities = {
  'clicked1': 0,
  'clicked2': 0,
  'clicked3': 0,
  'clicked4': 0,
};

function result() {
  for (let key in possibilities) {
    if (key !== 'clicked1' &&  possibilities[key] >= possibilities['clicked1']) {
      return "it did not work";
    }
  }
  return "it worked";
}

console.log(possibilities);
console.log("result() =", result());
possibilities['clicked1'] = 1;
console.log(possibilities);
console.log("result() =", result());
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to check if you found some element greater than `possibilities["clicked1"]`. If you found one, you will know `possibilities["clicked1"]` is not the max value, otherwise it will be the max value among all others. For approach this we can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get an array of values from your object, and then we use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to do the mentioned verification:

```js
var possibilities1 = {'clicked1': 6, 'clicked2': 3, 'clicked3': 4, 'clicked4': 5};
var possibilities2 = {'clicked1': 3, 'clicked2': 3, 'clicked3': 4, 'clicked4': 5};

function results(ps)
{
    let found = Object.values(ps).some(x => x > ps['clicked1']);
    found ? console.log("not worked") : console.log("worked");
};

results(possibilities1);
results(possibilities2);
```